# In my mixed effects model, are the confounded MCMC chains between my random intercepts and my global intercept problematic?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, hierarchical-bayesian, confounding, random-intercepts

I implemented an MCMC algorithm for the following regression model:

$$y_i \sim N(\mathbf{x}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta} + \eta(\mathbf{s}_i) + \theta_i,\sigma^2),$$

$$\boldsymbol{\beta}\sim N(\boldsymbol{0},10^6\mathbf{I}),$$

$$\boldsymbol{\eta} \sim N(\boldsymbol{0},\sigma^2_\eta\mathbf{R}(\phi)),$$

$$\boldsymbol{\theta}\sim N(\boldsymbol{0},10^6\mathbf{I}),$$

where $\eta(\mathbf{s}_i)$ are latent spatial random effects, $\theta_i$ are random intercepts, and we have a global intercept $\beta_0$ in the regression coefficients $\boldsymbol{\beta}$. There's more details to this Bayesian hierarchical model, but I'm not sure they're necessary. My main concern is that the MCMC chains for the global intercept $\beta_0$ and the random intercepts $\theta_i$ are inversely related (i.e., as the $\beta_0$ chain increases, every $\theta_i$ chain decreases - but $\beta_0+\theta_i$ is constant for each observation $i$). Is this okay despite the chains not technically converging, or does this point to something problematic?